# Use UserForm Command Button to head to specific line in moduel

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a custom UserForm with several command buttons. Is it possible than when you click one of the buttons it takes you to the next line from where you loaded the UserForm in the 1st place?

For example Module1 Line 5 opens up UserForm1 
You use UserForm1's features, 
Command button 7 then takes you back to Module Line 6 and you continue with the rest of your macro.

Does this make sense, if so how is it possible. I tried with GoTo lines, i know there bad pratice but can get them to work.

Below is my code, im not sure if i need to referance the Module im aiming for in the code?

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
GoTo LineRPMCheckDone
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Mark

Comment: why do you need to pause Module1 ?

Comment: i think that the form code takes over until the form closes, then the calling sub continues ... but if you really need to be sure ... define global variable `Dim formDone As Boolean`  then at Module1 line 6   `Do While Not formDone`  `Loop`  .... in the UserForm1 code, when done with form `formDone = true`